# how to save a point cloud?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i'm starting my first ros project :)
i have rviz up with a point cloud from a sensor.
how do i save that point cloud for offline testing?
i'd like to save just one frame as well as 10 minutes worth.

how can i do that?

thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11819/how-to-save-a-point-cloud?/) by [liquidmonkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/1325/liquidmonkey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2011-11-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at the following documentation pages:

- [rosbag](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag) can record and play ROS topics. This is the best way to record data if you want to emulate the live system behavior and/or avoid extra code to deal with file I/O.
- You can also [read](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/reading_pcd.php) and [write](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/writing_pcd.php) point clouds from/to PCD files.

---

Originally posted by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) with karma: 1951 on 2011-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [liquidmonkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/1325/liquidmonkey/) on 2011-11-07**:
bag_to_pcd is exactly what i'm looking for, thanks!

**Comment by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) on 2011-11-06**:
"rosbag play" publishes the recorded ROS topic, so you can visualize it pretty much the same way as if the data were live. There is also a tool bag_to_pcd in the pcl_ros package. It's your choice.

**Comment by [liquidmonkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/1325/liquidmonkey/) on 2011-11-06**:
looks great, thank you!

is it possible to convert a bag file into a pcd file for viewing of the point cloud?
or will rosbag play take care of that?